# SQLite like not returning expected results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I can't figure out why the following query returns `Pittman`

[image]

While this next one returns nothing

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing the "offset 5" remove the first 5 rows of result, which only left Pittman. Also it skip Pittman since only one row had returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SQLite provides two wildcards for constructing patterns. They are
> percent sign `%` and underscore `_` :
>
> The percent sign `%` wildcard matches any sequence of zero or more characters.
> The underscore `_` wildcard matches any single character.

So for the first query is pretty forward: `P` is any single character before `i` in Pittman

For the second, maybe the database data doesn't contains more than 5 Pi% and the offset jumps to null. Try witout limit and offset and tell me if it didn't work and I will glade to update my answer

Comment: removing the limit and offset will ensure that both queries return Pittman